# How to Parse String.format added 0's to int

Tags: java, string.format

I want to generate random national identification number and when i add 0's with String.format() to fill in digits, i can't parse it back into int

````
public class NinGenerator {

        public static void Generator(sex name){ // sex is enum

        Random rand = new Random();

        int year = rand.nextInt(60) + 40;   // For starting at year 40
        int month, day, finalNumbers;

        month = rand.nextInt(12) + 1;

        if(name == sex.FEMALE){ // In case of female
            month += 50;
        }

        switch(month){  // For max number of days to match given month
        ```
        case 1:
        case 3:
            day = rand.nextInt(30) + 1;
        ```
        }

        finalNumbers = rand.nextInt(9999) + 1;  // last set of numbers

        String nin = FillZeroes(year, 2) + FillZeroes(month, 2) + FillZeroes(day, 2) + FillZeroes(finalNumbers, 4); // Merging it into string

        // Here occurs error

        int ninInt = Integer.parseInt(nin); // Parsing it into number

        while(ninInt % 11 != 0){    // Whole number has to be divisble by 11 without remainder
            ninInt++;
        }

            System.out.println("National identification number: " + ninInt);

    }

    public static String FillZeroes(int number, int digits){    // For number to correspond with number of digits - filling int with zeros

        String text = String.valueOf(number);

        if(text.length() < digits){

            while(text.length() != digits){
                text = String.format("%d1", number);
            }
        }

        return text;
    }

}
````

I want to generate 10 digit number divisible by 11 without reminder, compiler always generates error on the line with parsing

Comment: Did you try FillZeroes() to check if it does what it is supposed to do?

Comment: Add bad `nin` value, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested out your code and I believe you are hitting the limit for how high an int can go.  If you try placing "2147483647" as your nin value it will run, but as soon as you go to "2147483648" you will get the same error.  If you want to fix this you might have to use a datatype such as a long or double depending on what you want to do with it.

[Here is a link showing the different datatypes and their ranges.](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_data_types.asp)

Comment: Yes, that was the problem i overlooked, now it's so simple, all i had to do, was use

long ninInt = Long.parseLong(nin, 10);

Answer (score 0):

Your FillZeroes() function could simply be:

```
public static String FillZeroes(int number, int digits)
{
    String format = "d" + digits.ToString();
    return number.ToString(format);
}
```